# How to get the full HTML content of an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an application where I want to save 100% of the contents of an iFrame. This includes the `<html>` tags also (if they exist).

I have only found a solution on how to save the iFrame's content starting from the  section.

```
var if = $('#myiframe').contents().find("html").html();
```

This however isn't good, because I don't know if theree always will be a HTML tag in the document. Also, the second problem with this approach is that it's not returning the `<html>` tags.

I need some function with which I can return everything inside of an iFrame with no excuse.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I have finally found a solution by doing the following:

```
var if = document.getElementById('#myiframe').contentWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

Comment: I thy this and I get a cross-origin frame block message. Any Idea of a workaround?